# What is the quickest way to convert a pandas dataframe to json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am running an API which runs a store procedure on a Sqlserver table into a dataframe and then return the result to the user in the form of Json. Below is the code I wrote which is working.

```
def call_proc(sql: str, connection):
    """
    :param sql: Call store procedure
    :return: Successful request - 200. Bad Request - 400.
    """
    try:
        dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=connection)
        print(f'duration to run sql: {datetime.datetime.now() - begin}')
        result = dataframe.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient="records")
        result = json.loads(result)
        print(f'duration to prepare result: {datetime.datetime.now() - begin}')
        return result, 200
    except Exception as e:
        return {'message': '{error}'.format(error=e)}, 400
    finally:
        logger.info('Closing the connection.')
        connection.close()
```

The string: `sql` contains the call statement of the store procedure.

The output looks like

```
[
    {
        "col1":"val1",
        "col2":"val2",
    },
    {
        "col1":"val1",
        "col2":"val2",
    }
]
```

The output of the store procedure has 20000 rows.
When I run the API which calls the above method, the response time of the API is 30 Seconds which is a lot slower to what my requirement is.
Is there any faster way to convert dataframe to Json ?

Attempt2:
I also tried to loop through the dataframe as below and return a json.

```
dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=connection)
query_result, json_result = "", {}
for ir in dataframe.itertuples():
    query_result = str(ir[1])
json_result = json.loads(query_result)
return json_result, 200
```

But the result is an error:
`{ "message": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" }`

I printed time taken in running the sql and preparing the json using print statements & the print statements from my log could be found below. The duration to run sql on sql server studio is 2 Seconds

```
duration to run sql: 0:00:06.666858
duration to prepare result: 0:00:08.328360
```

Attempt 3: Using Connection and SQL

```
json_data = []
rv = connection.execute(sql)
for result in rv:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(result.keys(), result)))
return json.dumps(json_data), 200
```

Even this takes the same amount of time as when I used pandas dataframe.

Comment: Maybe try some other options like df.to_dict ? Also try to make everything in one step (return xxxxx) instead of 2 steps (saving and loading). Just my 2 cents

Comment: @loaTzimas I added the second attempt. Can you tell me what is going wrong there ?

Comment: Hmm, i 'm not sure why that happened. Have you mesured the time of your sql query? Maybe the delay is there.

Comment: To prepare the json it is taking 25-26 seconds on average. To return the prepared result, another 4-5 seconds.

Comment: Where is the time consumed though? In sql or in python? This is crucial. If it's in sql then you cannot do much with changes in python

Comment: I added the time taken in each step using `print` statements. You can check the statements in the method and its result in `attempt-3`

Answer (score 0):

You're

- using Pandas to load SQL to a dataframe (which includes datatype inference and roundtripping)
- then using Pandas to turn that into a string of JSON
- then using Python's JSON library to turn that string back into a list
- then returning that from your view, which again stringifies it.

You should instead

- use a the native SQL connection you already have to run the query
- append rows from that result into a list
- return that list

Comment: I tried to do as you said. You can find it in attempt 3. The code still runs for 35seconds.

Comment: You can try a faster JSON serializer such as `orjson`, but in general: profile your code to see where the actual bottleneck is.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .to_json function to convert your dataframe to JSON
example.

```
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]],
    index=["row 1", "row 2"],
    columns=["col 1", "col 2"],
)

result = df.to_json(orient="split")
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)  
{
    "columns": [
        "col 1",
        "col 2"
    ],
    "index": [
        "row 1",
        "row 2"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "a",
            "b"
        ],
        [
            "c",
            "d"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: The output is in wrong format to the one I mentioned in the question.